# Displaying mysql with while & foreach in a proper way

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Im trying to display this table:

[image]

(To clarify: Uren = Hours, Maandag = Monday, Dinsdag = Tuesday, Woensdag = Wednesday, Donderdag = Thursday, Vrijdag = Friday.

Now im planning to show all data like this in different tables, on the same page in a some kind of "list":

```
Monday 
Hours: Monday   
1.     Index
2.     Index
3.     Index
4.     Index
5.     Index
6.     Index
7.     Index
8.     Index

  Tuesday
 etc. etc.
```

Same for all other days~

Only the first 8 hours all the time.
Now i got this code:

public function notLoggedIn($whichtable, $whichrow, $link, $preference, $dag, $uur)
        {
            $this->newfunction = new functions;

```
    $getvalue = $this->newGet();
    $resultaat = DB_connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $whichtable WHERE $whichrow = '$preference'");

    $days = array("Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag"); // take all dagen op
    $loop = array();

    while($rij = $resultaat->fetch_assoc())
    {
            $loop[] = $rij;
    }

    foreach ($days as $currentDay) 
    {   
    echo "<table style='float:left; width:100%;'>";     
        echo "<th></th><th style='width:100%; left:0; background-color:#9a136e; color:#fff; font-size:20px;'>
        <div style='margin-auto;'>$currentDay</div></th>";  
        foreach($loop as $test) 
        {   
            $day = $test[$currentDay]; 
            $uren = $test['Uren'];

            $getkleur = explode(",", $day); 

                    echo "<tr>"; ?> <th style='width:20%; display:$getkleur[5]; border-right:1px dotted #000;'>
                    <? $this->newfunction->linkToHoure($uren)?></th><?
                    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #999; display:$getkleur[5]; width:100%; height:40px;'>".$getkleur[0]."
                    <a style='font-size:24px; margin-top:-7px; position:absolute; right:0;' href='#'>></a></td></tr>

                    <tr><td></td><td style='width:100%;'><b><a style='background-color:$getkleur[4]; color:#fff;' href=''>".$getkleur[3]."</b>
                    <b><a style='color:#906;' href=''>". $getkleur[2]."</b></a></td></tr>";             
        } // close foreach
    echo "</table>";
    } 
    }// close notloggedin function
```

Now it does display everthing on the same page , but like this:

```
 1. (Index of monday). Monday
    1. (Index of Tuesday). Tuesday
    1. (Index of Wednesday). Wednesday
    1. (Index of Thursday). Thursday
    1. (Index of Friday). Friday
    2. (Index of Monday). Monday
    2. (Index of Tuesday). Tuesday
    2. (Index of Wednesday). Wednesday
    2. (Index of Thursday). Thursday
    2. (Index of Friday). Friday
```

Till 8... Instead of the example above.
But it should get seperated in hours & days.

I got no idea how to solve this. 
All help is appriciated..

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: He Nederlander, zo als die gast hierboven zij gebruik mysqli of pdo. Ook zou ik als ik jou was de opbouw van je db tabel herzien. Wat jij wild doen heeft weinig met php te maken. Je kan dat via de query zelf regelen maar je moet dan wel je tabel structuur aanpassen. Stackoverflow: sorry for the dutch english coming up. As #rekire said you should use mysqli or pdo. Also it is better to restructure your table. What you want to do is a task for the query and not for php.

Comment: Well i build already alot for this with this table, Could u give me a example how i could make this alot better than?:P , Mysql structure of tables has always been my weakness. I would appriciated if u could give me a tip to display it more "Dinamically"; Also in comment to Rekire, I was planning to first optimizing my code to work in mysql, and i will later do more about mysqli. since this is a school project.

Comment: I would really appriciate it though if someone had a proper answer please!. I made everthing btw Mysqli, it were a few little things which had to get changed. @rekire I updated the code.

Comment: @sirwilliam, Could u give me a example of how to do it? I have never been good in Table structures in mysql, im not using it really that often.

Comment: @iLuvCode when I have some time today I will take a look and give you an answer with new table structure concept + a query to get out the data like you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try switching the while and foreach parts.'For each day' should come first, then loop through the table with the actual day selected.

Formatting should be another part, but this ought to give you the desired 8 lines per day output.

Comment: This gives me only Monday, with 1 till 8. But mine example gives me the whole table only in the wrong order. But ur right, logically it would give me the desired result. Any thoughts on how i could change this code? I tryed already alot.

Comment: You have to reset the result pointer after each while, so you can iterate through the resultset again. You can do this by copying the data into an array before the first foreach, and iterate on the array with an internal foreach loop, or reset the dbresult pointer (in mysql it is mysqli_data_seek, but as you use a db framework you have to find the way how to do it with that)

Comment: I check some examples, its some time ago i did mysql. Thnx for ur idea.

Comment: I meant, if you use the plain mysql* functions in php, no need to dig into mysql for this, the solution should be in php side (the $resultaat object could have a reset() or rewind() for example)

Comment: Do u got a example? I never heard of such

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding earlier, but I'm really glad my idea could help you. Which method did you use in the end? I will (or you can) add that to the answer so others can read it in whole, not just through the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Oke I took a look and I think I've got what you want. First you make two tables in your db like:

A table for the daily events (I assumed they where school subjects. correct me If I'am wrong!):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vakken` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vaknaam` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

Insert some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `vakken` (`id`, `vaknaam`) VALUES
(1, 'Nederlands'),
(2, 'Engels'),
(3, 'Duits'),
(4, 'Wiskunde'),
(5, 'Rekenen'),
(6, 'programming php'),
(7, 'Biologie'),
(8, 'Grieks'),
(9, 'Geschiedenis'),
(10, 'Scheikunde');
```

Last table for the daily overview:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lesuren` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `les_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uur` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `dag` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;
```

Also insert some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `lesuren` (`id`, `les_id`, `uur`, `dag`) VALUES
(3, 4, 1, 1),
(4, 7, 2, 1),
(5, 5, 3, 1),
(6, 1, 4, 1),
(7, 0, 5, 1),
(8, 6, 6, 1),
(9, 3, 7, 1),
(10, 4, 8, 1),
(11, 10, 1, 2),
(12, 8, 2, 2),
(13, 9, 3, 2),
(14, 7, 4, 2),
(15, 6, 5, 2),
(16, 4, 6, 2),
(17, 3, 7, 2),
(18, 1, 8, 2),
(19, 10, 1, 3),
(20, 8, 2, 3),
(21, 9, 3, 3),
(22, 7, 4, 3),
(23, 6, 5, 3),
(24, 4, 6, 3),
(25, 3, 7, 3),
(26, 1, 8, 3),
(27, 10, 1, 4),
(28, 8, 2, 4),
(29, 9, 3, 4),
(30, 7, 4, 4),
(31, 6, 5, 4),
(32, 4, 6, 4),
(33, 3, 7, 4),
(34, 1, 8, 4),
(35, 10, 1, 5),
(36, 8, 2, 5),
(37, 9, 3, 5),
(38, 7, 4, 5),
(39, 6, 5, 5),
(40, 4, 6, 5),
(41, 3, 7, 5),
(42, 1, 8, 5);
```

As you can see the table only contains numbers. That is just the way we save stuff in db. We call that the model. Now we create some html we call that the view.

Fist make a php file with the name 'database.class.php' (Becouse I am so nice I made a simple db class for you with PDO = php data object. This is better than using the old function because they are deprecated):

```
<?php

    //Database class
    class db extends Pdo{

        private $inlog;
        private $pass;
        private $adres;
        private $dbname;

        public function __construct($dbname, $adres, $inlog, $pass){

            parent::__construct('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$adres, $inlog, $pass);

            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        public function doPrepare($queryString, $param){

            $query = $this->prepare($queryString);
            $query->execute($param);
            return $query;
        }

        public function doPrepareBind($queryString, $param){

            $query = $this->prepare($queryString);
            foreach($param as $par){
                switch($par[2]){
                    case 'int':
                        $query->bindParam($par[0], $par[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        break;
                    case 'str':
                        $query->bindParam($par[0], $par[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        break;
                    case 'blob':
                        $query->bindParam($par[0], $par[1], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $query->bindParam($par[0], $par[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        break;
                }
            }
            $query->execute();
            return $query;
        }
    }

?>
```

Now finally we can do some PHP. It actually is really short:

```
<?php

    require_once('database.class.php');

    // use construct like dbname - dbadres - login - pass
    $db = new db('test', 'localhost:3307', 'root', 'usbw');

    $query = $db->query("
                            SELECT l.`dag` , l.`uur` , v.`vaknaam` 
                            FROM  `lesuren` l
                            INNER JOIN  `vakken` v ON l.`les_id` = v.`id` 
                            ORDER BY l.`dag` , l.`uur` 
    ");

    $dagen = array(1 => 'Maandag',2 => 'Dinsdag',3 => 'Woensdag',4 => 'Donderdag',5 => 'Vrijdag');

    $html = '';
    $olddag = 0;
    while($row = $query->fetch()){

        if($olddag != $row['dag']){
            $html .= $dagen[$row['dag']].' <br>'; 
        }
        $html .= "$row[uur] - $row[vaknaam] <br>"; 
        $olddag = $row['dag'];
    }

    echo $html;

?>
```

You can see a live demo here (note my webserver in not always online): [demo](http://paperboat.tk/test/vakken/)

Comment: Ah lol nice, thnx alot, i try it. I got everthing in mysqli now, so i use that. I change my whole system now first:p, the only problem is that i got everthing sorted in klassen, for example i got 10 klassen, with each 5 days, with 8 hours, means i have to make 400 rows:p So i have to check how i solve that first.

Comment: Its a big system where i change color depending on the local / docent for the hour / visibility etc. etc. I use my system becouse i could explode everthing easily and update everthing easy in the database. With ur system i need to make like 400 rows and 6 tables for every preference... So i think i will stuck on my old system, sorry.

Comment: I test it though, since it looks nice, i could of course make instead of the vakken table for example colors & another table for docents, and everhting based on lesuren, Than it wouldn't care if i got one big table with 400 rows with all info in it.

Comment: I can't use this, the way i take info from my table and the amount, mine example is actually already fine. Thnx anyways for the afford u spended.

Comment: easy add extra table `klas` and with two fields named id(int) and klasname(varchar max 30) and add the id's to the lesuren. I make a change wait a sec.

Comment: This won't work for me. Could u give me a example how i can edit my excisting code to something which works for me? Check the anser under ures, he explaines how to reset the while , but i got no idea how. I get soon a excisting database, and i don't want to spend to much time only on database formatting, since thats useless for me now.

Comment: Solved, thnx alot :) I keep ur answer in mind for later formatting of the DB if necessary, it was really usefull:)